# Does HTML shift between monitors

Tags: html

For example, I did a button or header with html css, but my monitor is 1920x1080, but my friend's 1378x768. For example, according to my monitor, I put the button with a margin of 50%. Will there be a difference between my friend and my monitor? let's put 1600px with pixel or its monitor is 1378px wide, does the button not slip down?

Comment: It is the size of the browser window that matters. The screen resolution is irrelevant except insofar as it restricts the size of the browser window. (There are situations where pixel density becomes relevant but this isn't one of them).  You can test this by resizing your window.

Answer (score -1):

No, the display will vary , open the `devops` in you browser and try the resolution you want to see , Only thing to do is add `@media` queries .